# Using .setLocation() dosent seem to be working for JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So im trying to display a grid of bitmap tiles on a window.
I have a for loop that is populating the array of JLabels and using .setLocation() to define their position.
The problem is that when the frame is displayed, they seem to totally ignore the location that ive set for them.

Heres my code so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("game.demo");

    mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    mainFrame.setSize(512, 512);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    BufferedImage desTile16Image = ImageIO.read(new File("assets//desert_tile_16x.bmp"));
    ImageIcon desTile16Icon = new ImageIcon(desTile16Image);

    JLabel[][] map = new JLabel[32][32];




    for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++) {
        System.out.print(x + "\n");
        map[x][0] = new JLabel();
        map[x][0].setIcon(desTile16Icon);
        map[x][0].setLocation(x * 16, 0);
        mainPanel.add(map[x][0]);
    }

    //mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
    mainFrame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider something like...

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(32, 32));
```

Then you won't need `map[x][0].setLocation(x * 16, 0);`

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) more details

Comment: aaah I see, though is there a way to position the labels independently of a "layout"

Comment: You'd have to convince me of the use case for doing away with the layout manager...

Comment: okay so, on top of the tiles I would like to display a car bitmap that will eventually move about the place, pixle by pixle.

Comment: How is the car implemented? Is it a component of some kind?